# Does MySQL database connections pool expire if it was not used within long amount of time or if application which used it collapsed?

Tags: python, mysql

I am connecting database MySQL (MariaDB) from Python script using `MySQLConnectionPool`. I use context manager to hadle connection in the pool. I wonder if pool can expire if it is not used for a long amount of time or if my program collapsed. I've found that connection to MySQL db expires, do it is released even if you've forgot or have not been able to close connection in your program, what's situation with connections pool?

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector.errors import Error
from mysql.connector import pooling

SQL_CONN_POOL = pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(
    pool_name="mysqlpool",
    pool_size=1,
    user=DB_USER,
    password=DB_PASS,
    host=DB_HOST,
    database=DATABASE,
    auth_plugin=DB_PLUGIN
)

@contextmanager
def mysql_connection_from_pool() -> "conn":
    conn_pool = SQL_CONN_POOL  # get connection from the pool, all the rest is the same
    _conn = conn_pool.get_connection()
    try:
        yield _conn
    except (Exception, Error) as ex:
        # if error happened all made changes during the connection will be rolled back:
        _conn.rollback()
        # this statement re-raise error to let it be handled in outer scope:
        raise
    else:
        # if everything is fine commit all changes to save them in db:
        _conn.commit()
    finally:
        # actually it returns connection to the pool, rather than close it
        _conn.close()


@contextmanager
def mysql_curs_from_pool() -> "curs":
    with mysql_connection_from_pool() as _conn:
        _curs = _conn.cursor()
        try:
            yield _curs
        finally:
            _curs.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be time outed. There are two timeout configuration.

See [wait_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) and [interactive_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout)

Comment: is it any chance I can control lifespan of connections pool from python side? (unfortunately I am not allowed to change "Server System Variables")

Comment: I recommend to implement a reconnect. Lost Connection to database shoud not be a application error.

Comment: Shouldn't the connection pool responsible for the reconnect? That's normal in other languages: if a connection becomes invalid the pool replaces it.